# Tomcat - WebService - without Trust Store

Tags: web-services, tomcat, ssl

We have a Webservice Application running on Tomcat.

This is SSL secured. We need to share our public key to every client trying to access our web services. Is it possible to disable the trust certificate verification ?

Comment: Are you asking if clients can disable the requirement that they trust your server's certificate? Why would you want them to do that?

Comment: Just curiosity at the moment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, all TLS clients should verify the servers to which they are connecting. Any other default behavior would be dangerous.

The client is the party performing the verification in a one-way TLS handshake (that is, when there is no client-authentication being performed where the client also presents a certificate to the server).

There are only two ways to avoid distributing your server's certificate to all possible clients:

1. Get your server's certificate signed by a trusted Certificate Authority (CA)
2. Modify all possible clients to ignore any problems with your certificate (such as not trusting it)

These days, with free domain certificates available from e.g. [Let's Encrypt](https://www.letsencrypt.org/), it's silly not to use a certificate signed by a legitimate CA.